# upload functionality of image in JqGrid.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have multiple column in my jqgrid and i want the inline editing functionality. I have one column where image is going to be displayed and if user click the image it should provide the functionality of upload file but same functionality like that of simpleupload.js i.e. image should also be displayed when the image is selected.

I came across many example in which it provide example of inline editing, however when i made the

> editype:"image" & editable: true

it shows textbox and when i change to

> editype:"file" & editable: true

it only give me option of upload only. is there any example where i can find the upload functionality along with the image.

i am working on below fiddle example:

```
  var mydata = [{
    name: "Toronto",
    country: "Canada",
    continent: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg",
    stage:"1"
}, {
    name: "New York City",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg",
    stage:"2"
}, {
    name: "Silicon Valley",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg",
    stage:"2"
}, {
    name: "Paris",
    country: "France",
    continent: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg",
    stage:"1"
}]
var stages = { '1': 'Initiate', '2': 'Develop' };
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent","Stage"],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        index: 'country',

        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'continent',
        index: 'continent',
        editype:"image",
        formatter: function () {
                return "<img src='https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg' alt='my image' />";
            },
        editable: true
    },
    { name: 'stage', index: 'stage', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: stages } },

              ],
     gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    'cellEdit': true,
    'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    multiselect: true
});

$("#ctlAddRow").click(AddRow);               
function AddRow()
{
     var newRowId = $.jgrid.randId("new");
     var row={
    name: "",
    country: "",
    continent: "",
    stage:""}
     $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', newRowId, row); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67w3c4Lx/61/

**desired functionality is something like this:**
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/upload.html

Comment: Just change it to `edittype: 'file'` instead of `image`, like http://jsfiddle.net/67w3c4Lx/62/

Comment: @Hackerman i have tried that but when i select image it just show the file name with the upload buttton. what i want is when i select the image, image should be displayed instead of file name and when i click the image it provide the functionality uploading the file.

Comment: Then I think that you are following the wrong path....you should use an edit button that shows a modal where you can do the same that you do on datatable, but in jqgrid....it should be easier and more user friendly....something similar to this http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithImages.htm